# Winter 18 Error with reports and dashboards after enabling Lightning Report Builder

Tags: lightning-experience, bug, report-builder, winter18

I have tried to enable the Winter 18 new [Lightning Report Builder](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_rd_reports_lightning_report_builder.htm?edition=&impact).

So I have added a permission set to my user that has `Report Builder (Lightning Experience)` permission.

After doing that - I cannot enter anymore the `Reports` tab or any report, and the `Dashboards` tab or any dashboard.

I always get this error:

> Error in $A.getCallback() [Library include not defined: js://force.calendarLibrary.DateUtils]
>   FK.Df()@https://myorgname.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/N7IitgTrFKAhFRnZsZkeiA/aura_prod.js:406:97
>   V.Df()@https://myorgname.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/N7IitgTrFKAhFRnZsZkeiA/aura_prod.js:579:43
>   IK.Vi()@https://myorgname.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/N7IitgTrFKAhFRnZsZkeiA/aura_prod.js:407:396
>   V.Vi()@https://myorgname.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/N7IitgTrFKAhFRnZsZkeiA/aura_prod.js:578:385
>   fJ.Hc()@https://myorgname.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/N7IitgTrFKAhFRnZsZkeiA/aura_prod.js:258:400
>   V.Hc()@https://myorgname.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/N7IitgTrFKAhFRnZsZkeiA/aura_prod.js:567:59
>   V.Bb()@https://myorgname.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/N7IitgTrFKAhFRnZsZkeiA/aura_prod.js:583:323
>   V.tf()@https://myorgname.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/N7IitgTrFKAhFRnZsZkeiA/aura_prod.js:559:368
>   l()@https://myorgname.lightning.force.com/libraries/force/componentLibrary/components.js:1:278
>   Object.h.createPanel()@https://myorgname.lightning.force.com/libraries/force/componentLibrary/components.js:2:15

[image]

So I have removed the permission, but still I get this error whenever I want to open a report or report tab or dashboard or dashboards tab, and cannot enter these pages.

This is a bug for sure, but what can I do to get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works and the problem is solved, I do not know what fixed this, maybe Salesforce fixed it on the background.

But still - I cannot use Lightning Report Builder - I get always the old report builder, I think I will ask a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

Have you also enabled "Enable Lightning Report Builder (Beta)" in the "Report and Dashboard (User Interface) Settings" ?

Mind you on the Community, it was mentioned that it has not yet been rolled out to Sandboxes?
https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00003Erc5x

It is available in my pre-release org though, and working, after having turned it on, and assigning myself the permission

Comment: All my settings where ok, anyway - now it works and the problem is solved, I do not know what fixed this, maybe Salesforce fixed it on the background, but - I cannot use `Lightning Report Builder` - I get always the old report builder